Is there a way to make a function which automatically group vectors?
I'm trying to create a function that automatically group sequence vectors, where I can choose different signs/text to separate both the numbers and the groups. But have run into some obstacles.
The basis for the function is:
test_group <- c(2:4, 7:10, 14, 20:21)
a_function <- function(test_group, to_from = " to ", sep_group = "; ")

The Output I'm trying to get
a_function (test_group)
[1] "2 to 4; 7 to 10; 14; 20 to 21"

What I have done
I've managed to get the correct output by manually adding numbers, and using paste  function:
test_group <- c(2:4, 7:10, 14, 20:21)
to_from <- c(' to ')  
sep_group <- c('; ')

a_function <- function(test_group){  
   x1 <- paste ( 2, 4, sep=to_from)
   x2 <- paste ( 7,10, sep=to_from)
   x3 <- paste( 14, sep=to_from)
   x4 <- paste( 20,21, sep=to_from)  
   print (paste (x1, x2, x3, x4, sep=sep_group))
}

[1] "2 to 4; 7 to 10; 14; 20 to 21"
But ideally I'd like to automatic the process, so that the numbers in the text group can be changed (e.g. from a list from 0 - 100) without needing to change the function.
Any advice?

Maybe you can use diff + cumsum to tag the groups, and then convert the groups into strings
paste0(
  by(
    x,
    cumsum(c(1, diff(x) != 1)),
    \(v) ifelse(length(v) == 1, v, paste0(min(v), " to ", max(v)))
  ),
  collapse = "; "
)

which gives
"2 to 4; 7 to 10; 14; 20 to 21"


The seqid function in collapse can perform the grouping and then we apply the indicated function to each group.
library(collapse)
library(magrittr)

vec2char <- function(x) if (length(x) == 1) x else paste(min(x), "to", max(x))
test_group %>%
  tapply(., seqid(.), vec2char) %>%
  paste(collapse = "; ")
## [1] "2 to 4; 7 to 10; 14; 20 to 21"

